# Make overflow ignore specific child element

Tags: html, css

I need to put a large cover image at the top of a page. It's wider than my 960px content wrapper so I'll put it outside of that, but I don't want it causing the page to scroll horizontally due to its width. Is there an established way to make a container ignore a specific child when it comes to scrolling?

My first thought was to make it the centered background of a div with 100% width, but the image is dynamic and shouldn't be assigned by the CSS.

Comment: I still want the  page to scroll horizontally if it gets thinner than the wrapper, and I don't want to scale the image, it should be fixed width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `max-width:100%` on the image, this will scale it down to fit if it's too big at full size (just make sure that `height` is either not set or `auto`)

Alternatively, you can use a background image, but have the "image" part be `none` in your external CSS. Then, where you would have `src="path/to/image.png"` in your `<img />`, instead just put `style="background-image:url('path/to/image.png');"`

Comment: thinking the second might be the best scenario